# How to display a database columns using CRUD in play framework?

Tags: java, playframework, crud, postgresql-9.1

I want to display the data of a postgresql database using the CRUD in the play framework; I looked for any examples to get idea which I didn't find after a long time of  searching in google. Someone help me with this if you can or post a valid link regarding this. Thanks in advance!

I use, Play 1.2.5, java and postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do this in your application code in runtime.

You can execute query using DB plugin to search DB metadata using native PostgreSQL queries.
Here's an example how to get column names of my system DOCUMENT table:

```
List<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
ResultSet result = DB.executeQuery("select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = 'DOCUMENT';");
while(result.next()) {
    String column = result.getString(1);
    columns.add(column);
}
```

This note that code is somewhat simplified and you should use prepared statements if anything in this query will be inserted from data that user or any other system entered.

Use `DB.getConnection().prepareStatement()` to get `PreparedStatement` instance.

Comment: Thanks for your response! First I did not mention clearly what I want I think; now I have edited the post. It is possible to to do this by configuring the 'application.conf' file in the play! but I want to do this using the jdbc conneciton from java.